# How to change default value of Facet.limit in Solr

Tags: solr

I have reviewed Solr this document [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.limit). As per this document Solr returns 100 records for facets. What if I want fetch more records. How can I change default value for facet records?

I do not want to get it through Solr query. Is there any way to change its default value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `requestHandler name="/select"` you can set the any value you want. If you are using some other `requestHandler` then set it in the respective `requestHandler` as per your needs.

```
<lst name="defaults">
  ....
  <str name="facet.limit">1000</str>
  ....
</lst>
```